# Create graphs from databases in Notion

Tags: pie-chart, notion-api, mermaid, notion

I am aware of and use Mermaid, the native graphical integration in notion, and it works great. It just can't take data from databases, and I don't want to update the same data everywhere constantly.
Does anyone know how I can get a pie chart (or any graphical representation of data) to obtain values from a database?

I've tried using Graphext but cannot get my database to link. I am probably missing a detail somewhere, but that isn't the point. I am curious to find out if there is some way I can do this natively in notion.
Or should I simply get familiar with the API and somehow pull a rabbit out of my hat and create my integration?